# How to change the name of a datafield in a dataset?

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics-cloud

I am about to append two datasets. But the rule for append is that the  corresponding columns must be in the same order and have the same name and field type.

Right now, both the datasets have same order and field type but their names are different.

Is there any way to change the name of the datafield?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to ‘Override to the Schema section’ in the Wave Integration Document. Schema section allows to change object and field attributes. In your example, name field needs to changed in all dataset or change the one to make it similar to another one.

Also, this might require a series of transformation. During this transformation you might be required to change the field metadata also.
For further example, please refer to Wave Integration Guide document [https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/bi_admin_guide_data_integration_guide.pdf](http://Refer%20to%20%E2%80%98Override%20to%20the%20Schema%20section%E2%80%99%20of%20the%20transformation%20in%20the%20Wave%20Integration%20Document..%20Schema%20section%20allows%20to%20change%20object%20and%20field%20attributes.%20In%20your%20example,%20name%20field%20needs%20to%20changed%20in%20all%20dataset%20or%20change%20the%20one%20to%20make%20it%20similar%20to%20another%20one.%20%20Also,%20this%20might%20require%20a%20series%20of%20transformation.%20During%20this%20transformation%20you%20might%20be%20required%20to%20change%20the%20field%20metadata%20also.%20For%20further%20examle,%20please%20refer%20to%20Wave%20Integration%20Guide%20document%20https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/bi_admin_guide_data_integration_guide.pdf%20%20Overriding%20Salesforce%20field%20Metadata%20also%20provides%20some%20handle%20to%20change%20the%20metadata%20of%20the%20dataset,%20depending%20on%20the%20situation.)

Overriding Salesforce field Metadata also provides some handle to change the metadata of the dataset, depending on the situation.